How to check the order of continuity of a function?
I was reading on the topic of order of continuity and came up with this question.
Is there a maximum $k$ such that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is in $C^{k}$ but not in $C^{k+1}$?.
I was wondering if there is a way of knowing this for specific functions or if there even exit such functions. Other than looking at how the function is to check for exponential or polynomial parts to see if it is $C^{\infty}$, I don't know if you can derive which class a function belongs to. Another possible way could be to integrate a $C^{0}$ function $k$ times if it is possible to find a $C^{k}$ function.

Consider the family of functions : $|x|$, $|x| \times x$, $|x| \times x^2$, $|x| \times x^3$,...

@SineoftheTime I want to know if given a function $f$ you can derive which $C^k$ class it belongs to. This question is simple for $C^{0}$ and $C^{\infty}$ but I don't know how to derive which class $C^k$ a function belongs to in general.

@Anthony Thanks for the example of such functions. Do you know if there exists a way to determine which class a function belongs to?

Apart from the "direct" and "general" method of :

Try do derive $f$ as many times as possible, if you have to stop at some point because the last function you get is no longer derivable, let's say after k times, then ask yourself is $f^{(k)}$ continuous? If so then it is $C^{k}$, otherwise it is $D^{k}$ which satisfies :
$C^{k} \subsetneq D^{k} \subsetneq C^{k-1}$. So if it is $D^{k}$, it is $C^{k-1}$. If you can go on forever then it is $C^{\infty}$. But maybe someone else knows other methods and can answer you more precisely.

